# What is the current status of the Helios project?

Tags: asp.net, owin

Exactly one year ago there were some posts from Microsoft about project Helios. This was an OWIN implementation to self host your servers using IIS in a light way. The last Nuget package is from march 2014 [Project Helios](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.IIS/).

Does somebody know what is the current status of this project? Did they include it in the ASP.NET vNext implementation?

Comment: I didn't ask to recommend me anything! I just wanted to know the current status of a product. What could attract opinionated answers? An answer to this question cannot be opinionated at all. Am I missundestanding something?

Comment: I agree, this question should be reopened. There is a clear answer - Project Helios was merged into ASP.NET and was renamed to Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS.

Comment: Thank you CyberMonk. This is clearly an answer to a normal question.

Answer (score 4):

According to [these](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/95#issuecomment-69256313) [comments](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/98#issuecomment-69258136) on GitHub there will be another release. However, a few days ago someone else on the team told me there wasn't another release planned so I'm not sure who's right. Hopefully they do another update for those of us unable to migrate to vNext at the moment.

Project Helios is now part of ASP.NET vNext and is how you host your applications in IIS. The vNext NuGet package was renamed to [Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS)